# How install gapps with adb commands

Tags: adb, google-apps

How can I install google apps with adb commands ?
I don't know how to unzip . 
I used busybox. But it is not useful.
Please guide me .
Thanks to all and everythings. :)

Comment: No chance without unzip if you want to use anything other than the recovery-install-procedure described in [Flow's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/48224/16575). See also: [How do I properly install a system app given its .apk?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27/16575). Note, however, that to my knowledge the `adb install` doesn't handle system apps (parts of GApps need to be installed as system apps), so this variant won't work for you.

Answer (score 21):

If you have a rooted phone with a custom recovery, you can do it:

1. Reboot to recovery
2. Go into Sideload (might be under advanced - if your recovery doesn't have this feature, then you need to update your recovery.
3. On your computer, run `adb sideload <gapps-version.zip>`
4. Reboot.

Comment: this works ... note NO need to unzip as other comments suggest

Answer (score 6):

Good question. While it's technically feasible (mount /system rw, unpack the zip, install the apks), I don't think that it is currently possible.

The gapps are usually installed with help of the recovery. For more information see ["How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)