# Failed on cp file to /system - Cross-device link

Tags: adb, mount

I'm trying to `mv` `.apk` file from my `/sdcard` to `/system` and getting following error:

> failed on 'XXX.apk' - Cross-device link

I did `remount` my `/system` as `rw`

```
root@ghost:/ # mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system
root@ghost:/ # mount | grep system                                             
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
root@ghost:/ #
```

I also tried following, but without luck(

```
mbp:~ alexus$ adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
mbp:~ alexus$ adb remount
remount failed: Permission denied
mbp:~ alexus$
```

Why can't I still move apk file to /system? What am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

and the answer is pretty simple, use `cp` instead of `mv`)

Comment: for completeness: subsequently `rm` i.e. delete the original

Comment: This is a limitation of the Busybox `mv`. When the original `mv` encounters a move across device borders, it just does exactly `cp` followed by `rm`, tho I think it sets the file's time to the old values.

Comment: Adding to alexus's answer: If you don't have busybox, you can simply use cat SOURCE > DESTINATION to imitate cp

Comment: use "busybox mv <from> <to>". Works for me all the time.

Comment: @johnny you can't use `cat` to copy binary, cat would only work for text file.

Comment: @alexus Sure? I doubt that. There are even instructions to "flash" recoveries this way, and they work (I have an LG P880 whose bootloader is so rudimentary that it doesn't even offer support for `fastboot flash` (at least I never managed to get to that), so this is how I installed TWRP to it: `cat /sdcard/twrp.img > /dev/block/mmcblk0p1`). So are you saying that's a "text file"? :)