# How to install system app on Lollipop as su doesn't exist

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, apk, system-apps

I want to install a system apk (its the Dialer.apk) on Lollipop and am following these instructions

[How do I properly install a system app given its .apk?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27/how-do-i-properly-install-a-system-app-given-its-apk)

However after doing adb shell I get an unfound error trying to run su:

/system/bin/sh: su: not found

What's the problem?

UPDATE
------ After a bit of googling I found something that says the SU binary isn't present in Lollipop. If that's the case then how can I install an apk to system?

Comment: Not an answer to su command, but you can use this app [/system/app/](https://play.google.com/store/search?c=apps&q=/system/app/+apk) to switch to system app. Just install normally then open the app I provided the link for. Then reboot. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what app are you talking about? There's dozens of apps in the link you provided.

Comment: Android never ships with root access (su) unless you use a custom ROM. You need to [root your device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device).

Comment: @Sausages - [Here is the correct link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover&hl=en). Sorry about that. You need root for this app.