# Convert to system app by manually moving the APK to "system/app" folder in Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, system-apps

I was checking `/system/app` folder structure in Android L and realized that it has a new folder structure. It has introduced a new folder with APK name between `app` folder and the APK, e.g. `/system/app/test/test.apk`

If I want to install `test.apk` as a system app, how can I install it without installing it via "User app"? Can I just copy and paste `test.apk` from `/sdcard` to `/system/app` folder and give desired permission?

Comment: Very related, or duplicate of: [How do I properly install a system app given its .apk?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27/how-do-i-properly-install-a-system-app-given-its-apk?rq=1), though there's no answer explaining the difference on Android Lollipop.

Comment: I have already read that thread but can't satisfy with......

Comment: Yes, do it and reboot as well. Done. Oh, don't give desired permission but the appropriate permission, which would be same as the rest of the APKs have.

Comment: Okay i will do this and let you know, that it is working or not